# Can non-British wizards attend Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, wizards

Is there any evidence of non-British wizards attending Hogwarts?

Comment: the schools themselves seem to be kinda like country guarded secrets, we see throughout the book that the schools dont want to leek knowledge to other schools. i would hazzard that the quote from draco of the potential to switch schools, was more an exception being that the headmaster was an X death eater, and friends to the malfoys.

Comment: @Himarm, Draco going to Durmstrang was without any switch involved. He would have gone there without ever going to Hogwarts so he couldn't leak them any knowledge of Hogwarts (other then what his parents or others told him about Hogwarts, but so can anyone that attended Hogwarts)

Comment: @ThomasDB i was referring more to the schools being state secrets, so not that Draco would contaminate hogwarts as a student, but that a British national went to a foreign school, to then bring their secrets back to Briton, with the possibility that he would then teach at hogwarts and share durmstrangs secrets. I believe the Russians did this during the cold war, essentially sending loyal families to live in the states, to more accurately glean social trends, information, and potential sabotage.

Comment: @Himarm Ow ok, interpreted it wrong then. Carry on :D My bad.

Comment: Who'd **want** to attend Hogwarts? They don't have fountains and fun, and they don't study Dark Arts, and they have all the deadly stuff happening.

Comment: I am an Indian and I am a Hogwarts scholar major in DADA.

Comment: I think you mean other than GB or Ireland. Interestingly the term "Great Britain" was first used in 1474 nearly 500 years after Hogwarts was founded.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't remember any direct statement in the books saying that some student does not come from Britain.

There is some canon evidence that wizards can attend foreign schools though. Draco says that he considered going to Durmstrang but his mother opposed because it was too far away:

> … Father actually considered sending me to Durmstrang rather than Hogwarts, you know. He knows the Headmaster, you see. Well, you know his opinion of Dumbledore – the man’s such a Mudblood-lover – and Durmstrang doesn’t admit that sort of riff-raff.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire  Chapter 11: *Aboard the Hogwarts Express*.

One more indirect evidence can be found in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*.
Lupin says there that this year it is mandatory for all children to go to Hogwarts and that is did not use to be like this. Some parents were allowed to educate their kids at home or **abroad**:

> ‘Attendance is now compulsory for every young witch and wizard,’ he replied. ‘That was announced yesterday. It’s a change, because it was never obligatory before. Of course, nearly every witch and wizard in Britain has been educated at Hogwarts, but their parents had the right to teach them at home or send them abroad if they preferred.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, Chapter 11: *The Bribe*.

So it sounds plausible that also non-British students are allowed to study in Hogwarts.

Comment: However it's very clear in the books that Durmstrang is an international institute/school. I'm inclined to think that Hogwarts only admits young wizards and witches from the British Isles.

Comment: Updated the answer with one more canon source that hints to the fact that families were allowed to send their children to study abroad. So I find it VERY plausible that Hogwarts was also open to children from other countries.

Comment: I added the quotes for you, feel free to rollback the answer if you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I'll try to get hold on the books in English for further answers/questions.

Comment: There are also Asians and Chinese attending the school, although that may be because they actually live in Britain

Answer (score 5):

### They can not

> **Can American kids go to Hogwarts?**
>
> **J.K. Rowling:** *No, they have their own school. You'll find out in Book 4. Hogwarts just serves Britain and Ireland.*
>
> <sub>["World Exclusive Interview with J K Rowling," *South West News Service*, 8 July 2000](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/0700-swns-alfie.htm)</sub>

Comment: Rowling's response there seems to contradict quotes from the book.

Comment: @Ellesedil - Not really. Hogwarts rejecting foreign students doesn't mean Durmstrang does too. It also doesn't mean that Draco Malfoy is any more trustworthy than usual.

Answer (score 2):

## It seems so - Leta’s father was French.

Though the vast majority of Hogwarts students are British, Leta Lestrange attended Hogwarts, despite her father, Corvus Lestrange Sr., being French. From what is known about Leta’s history, it seems likely that she was born and lived the first few years of her life there as well.

> “**SCENE 100**
>   
> **EXT. PARK—1896—DAY**
>
> *We see a beautiful woman, LAURENA, dressed in an exquisite gown, walking through a park with her husband, MUSTAFA—clearly in love. A YOUNG YUSUF by their side.*
>
> **KAMA (V.O.)**
>   
> My mother, Laurena, was equally high-bred—a noted beauty. They were deeply in love. They knew a man of great influence, from a famous French pureblood family. He desired her.
>
> *Watching from a distance, an intense wizard, CORVUS LESTRANGE SR., studies her beauty.*” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald (The Original Screenplay)*</sup></sub>

While it is not explicitly stated where Leta was born, since her father was French and her mother was compelled to be with him by the Imperius Curse, it seems likely she would have been born in her father’s native France, where he was from and most likely living at the time.

> “**SCENE 101**
>   
> **INT. KAMA MANSION—1896—NIGHT**
>
> *LAURENA’S gown changes to a nightdress. She is walking slowly downstairs, a supernatural wind blowing.*
>
> **KAMA (V.O.)**
>   
> Lestrange used the Imperius Curse to seduce and abduct her . . .
>
> *The twelve-year-old KAMA runs after his mother, tugs at her hand, and tries to pull her back upstairs. She throws him off. The front door flies open. LESTRANGE SR. stands at the foot of the garden path. LAURENA walks toward him. KAMA chases after her. LESTRANGE SR. points his wand at KAMA and sends him sprawling.*
>
> *LAURENA lies on the bed as IRMA carries a newborn swaddled in a blanket to LESTRANGE SR.*” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald (The Original Screenplay)*</sup></sub>

If this is true, while it may be rare, this would prove it is indeed possible for a non-British child to attend Hogwarts.

Answer (score 0):

Canada is part of the British Commonwealth and while MACUSA is in the US - the way JK Rowling inserted a Canadian, Natalie McDonald, into her book and sleighted her in Gryffindor as a gesture to the girl from Toronto dying of cancer - I suspect both MACUSA AND the British Ministry view Canada as a sort of gray area.

On one hand, Lupin states outright that wizards were known to send their students abroad because Hogwarts WASN'T mandatory before. And of course people already mentioned Draco Malfoy nearly going to Durmstrang. There were also exchange programs for students to go to Castlebruxo from Hogwarts and Beauxbatons, so who knows. This lends credence to the theory that if an international wizard put all the necessary requirements in for the Book of Admittance and the Quill of acceptance to allow an international student to attend, it was possible. Especially since Canada is still part of the British Commonwealth as we are under the Crown and our Charter of Rights and Freedoms isn't a real "constitution" but a Charter. If we follow that train of thought, then yes, absolutely.

Conversely, JK Rowling flatly denied Americans were allowed to attend Hogwarts in an interview she did in the year 2000. That they had their own school. A school revealed later to be Ilvermorny. While Ilvermorny does have roots in Hogwarts history - founded by a Slytherin no less - it is its own entity. If MACUSA holds sway over the Great White North, that could be a problem (a problem even the wiki supports might I add.)

On the other hand, in the same 2000 interview, Rowling said we'd know the American school in Goblet of Fire. In the book they only state "Salem Witches Institute" which it turns out got retconned out as some local witch activist group or something to that effect and it wasn't til the 2010s and after Deathly Hallows did she create Ilvermorny. So how much stock you want to put into JK Rowling's canonicity when she's retconned her books before is entirely subjective.

Conclusion? In my belief, I think Canadians *can* attend Hogwarts, though it's an uphill battle and rarer because of the stupid book and quill being a stubborn lot, the international travel being a headache, and everything goes right. Because of this, I suspect most parents would rather just send their students to Ilvermorny because of distance, less border trouble, and probably because family attended there previously. The only reason a Canadian would end up at Hogwarts is because they have family ties in the UK, good friends with the Headmaster and Ministry, the book decided to be nice for a change as it can detect magical beings from everywhere, or a combination of them all. On a personal note? If I was a wizard? My family would've sent me to Hogwarts at the drop of a Sorting Hat (though not before my parents had a considerable row over it).

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SciFi Exchange. Could you please [edit] your answer with some quotes from the relevant books, and sources for your other claims